# How to specify default parameters for Response::json()

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way to specify default parameters for Response::json()?
The problem is that, in my case, Response::json($data) returns utf8 and since that I need to specify extra parameters to be able to read it:

```
$headers = ['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8'];
return Response::json(Course::all(), 200, $headers, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

That’s quite tiresome and looks like superfluous …

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new method in your (base) controller to set all those headers.

```
protected function jsonResponse($data) {
    $headers = ['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8'];
    return Response::json($data, 200, $headers, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

and then return your response like this in your controller route:

```
return $this->jsonResponse(Course::all());
```

Or you could create a new UTF8JsonResponse class extending the default `Response`, setting all the headers in the constructor, and returning that `return new UTF8JsonResponse(Course::all())`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but here's something that works quite well.

First create your own `ResponseFactory` class e.g.:

```
namespace App\Factories;

class ResponseFactory extends \Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory {
    public function json($data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [], $options = 0) {
        // If we haven't passed options manually override the default. 
        // You can always change this to always override the default
        if (func_num_args() < 4) { 
            $options = JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;
        }
        return parent::json($data, $status, $headers, $options);
    }
}
```

Then in your `AppServiceProvider` set the container to resolve your `ResponseFactory` whenever a response factory interface is required:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        // ... Other things
        $this->app->singleton(ResponseFactory::class, \App\Factories\ResponseFactory::class);
    }

    // Rest of class

}
```

Now, whenever you call `Response::json($variable)` your override will run instead of the default. Since your override extends the built-in default response factory everything else should work the same.

Comment: In Laravel 8 `AppServiceProvider` it works like so: 

`$this->app->singleton(\Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class, \App\Factories\ResponseFactory::class);`